# How to set PDEColorValue?

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to write some text to a PDF, and my problem is with the color. I am using the RGB Color Space, and this is what my code looks like.

```
memset(&pdeColorValue, 0, sizeof(PDEColorValue));
pdeColorValue.color[0] = FloatToFixedAS(255.0f);
pdeColorValue.color[1] = FloatToFixedAS(0.0f);
pdeColorValue.color[2] = FloatToFixedAS(0.0f);
```

Now the above gives me a nice red color and everything's fine. But when I want to change the color to, say a brown (R,G,B = 100,0,0), if I set the first value to 100.0f, it still gives me the same red color. How am I to get the desired colors?

Comment: Yes, that's it Shai, thanks!
But why is it so hard to find that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the range from `0 <= x <= 255` to `0 <= x <= 1.0`

I'm not very familiar with `PDEColorValue`, but it's quite common for RBG values to be either a decimal between 0 and 1.0.

It is true that 255 is a correct value for RGB parameters, yet again, each implementation is different.